# Custom permissions using HATEOS in REST JSON

Tags: json, restful-architecture

I have an API with Search (GET), Create (POST) and Update method (PUT) on a resource.

The Update (PUT) operation supports update of parameters such as 'name', 'value' and 'status'. The permission for updating 'status' is different from updating other parameters.

When UI reads the GET (search) response it enable update of fields(name, value and status) based on the permissions returned. Planning to return permissions using HATEOS as below.

```
"self": {
            "href": "https://mobile-services.test.com/api/V1/area/resorce/{resourceId}",
            "methods": [ "GET", "POST" ]
        },
```

Is it allowed return custom values (such as "POST-Status") for 'methods" key? If no, please suggest a way of handling the permissions in this scenario.